# Being charged on a per-app license, rather than to a per-user Power Apps license. Why?

Tags: powerapp, licensing, power-platform

I have been learning about Power Apps on a tenant that I have set up. I have installed the Center of Excellence and have been looking through the various apps within the solution. I recently looked at my bill for the last month, and found that I had been charged, on a per-app plan, for 5 different apps, at least 3 of which I'm sure I have created myself. After contacting Microsoft Support, they recommended that I delete the free trial plans (*Power Apps trial plan 2* and *Power Automate trial*). As a result I now only have 2 licenses that I am using:

- Microsoft 365 Business Standard
- Power Apps per user plan

Is this the correct way to make sure that a Power Apps per-user license is the overriding license, which then covers any additional Power Apps I may create? (or are there any additional steps I need to take so that I am not charged on a per-app plan when creating/using apps?)